# Different font for Some activities using Calligraphy Library

Tags: android, fonts, android-styles

I am using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) Library for using custom font in my application. I set a custom font to my whole application by default font using `CalligraphyConfig`, in my `Application` class in the `#onCreate()` method and it is working fine. Problem comes when I need to change font of one activity (SettingsActivity).

I tried using custom font in [style](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy#custom-font-defined-in-theme) however It didn't change the font of activity.

Following is the code of Style

```
    <style name="EnglishActivitiesTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf</item>
    </style>
```

In Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/EnglishActivitiesTheme"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Am I doing something wrong with custom font though style method? or Is there better method of doing this?

Comment: have you added attachBaseContext in your activity?

Comment: @EagleEye Yes I have done this. As I said default custom font is working fine.

Comment: You approach with the style seems to be good... But I read in the readme of lib maybe something interesting: `Default - if defined in the CalligraphyConfig this is used of none of the above are found OR if one of the above returns an invalid font.` Do you have some invalid font ? It could be an issue like this (I hope it is because, if not, it'll be more complicated to fix)

Comment: @LaurentMeyer I think the default font is not invalid because it is working good. and the activity font i am changing is also not invalid because it is roboto font downloaded from google.

Comment: Do you want to change the font for some elements in the activity or for the whole activity  ??

Comment: @Abhishek whole activity.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that. But you can change font for individual elements.

Comment: changing font for individual items not suitable for me. :(

Comment: @AhmadNawaz, I have tried couple of ways. But the situation remains same. To override the default font, either you have to apply your chosen font to each view individually (either in xml or programmatically) or you have to use default android font by removing the attachBaseContext() method from your activity. :(

Comment: @Abhishek thanks. I am using default font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it's because of AppCompat creating a different version of buttons/textviews at runtime.

In your Calligraphy startup in your Application, add the line:

```
.addCustomStyle(AppCompatTextView.class, android.R.attr.textViewStyle)
```

to end up with something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/some-other-custom-font.ttf")
                            .addCustomStyle(AppCompatTextView.class, android.R.attr.textViewStyle)
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}
```

And that should take care of your textviews.

Edit:

This should now be fixed with https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/pull/191, currently as a snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Not Best Solution however better than custom font in that activity.

I just removed

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

from activity where I was trying to change font. In That activity using default android font which is better than that custom font for my other activities.